# how to delete item from listview and refresh that

Tags: android-listview, arraylist, switch-statement, contextmenu, menuitem

I need some help in my homework here...
I want to do a listview with itens from editText.. but I dont know how to delete and edit the item, I tryed to use ContextMenu. I will post my code, and if you think that i have to change anything, tell me.. I'm begginer.

```
private Button bt;
private ListView lv;
private EditText et;
private ArrayList<String> Arraylt = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_l);

    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    lv.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,  
                int posicao, long id) {
             Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
             et.setText(String.valueOf(o));
          bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addadicionar();

        }
    });

}   


public void addadicionar() {
    Arraylt.add(et.getText().toString());
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arraylt));
    et.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey this is my note pad code it will help you .. have a look

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
if (v.getId()==R.id.listView1)
 {
                  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
              }
        }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();


              switch(item.getItemId()) {

                  case R.id.edit:
                    // edit stuff here
                        return true;
                  case R.id.delete:


ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);

 Cursor cursor2=mydb1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM notes;", null);

                        data.remove(info);

                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                        cursor2.moveToPosition(info.position);
                       int id= cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndex("id"));

    mydb1.delete("notes", "id=?", new String[]    {Integer.toString(id)});

list(view);   // this will refresh my list by calling my  display list method here        

                      return true;


                  default:

                      return super.onContextItemSelected(item);


              }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the item from listItems(List), then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: that was very useful. Thanks man but I dont use and dont knlow how to use SQ yet. Your 'delete item' wasn't help me. (i will try to do it with SQ like your code..who know?..)

Comment: okay it's fine if you don't want to use sq lite than don't use it and use another part of code which is related to adapter or list :) i am sure your answer is hidden in this code ..you just need to extract in right way :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

// note : you need to create xml file in res/menu folder which conatain deleter and editer item

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
if (v.getId()==R.id.listView1)
 {
                  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
              }
        }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();


              switch(item.getItemId()) {

                  case R.id.Deletar:
                    // edit stuff here
                        return true;
                  case R.id.editar:


ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);


                        data.remove(info);

                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                       list(view);   // this will refresh my list by calling my  display //list method here        

                      return true;


                  default:

                      return super.onContextItemSelected(item);


              }
```

Comment: Perfect man! one question more.. i put here "my_listview(view)" and show anything wrong.. it ask for create a local variable "view".. so.. what is this view?

Comment: where you trying to add my_listview(view) ? please show your code if possible .

Comment: my code, in this part is absolutely the same yours..I add the menu called main.xml, in the part "R.layout.simple_list" i put Arraylt and no data..(my string), going under "Arraylt.remove(info), after set adapter and after "lv(view)". I changed only that
`ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arraylt);
   
   
   Arraylt.remove(info);
   
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   
   lv(view);
   `

Comment: I give up about switch.. I changed my code, taking out a context menu.. Now Im using OnItemClick and I get the item from listview and set to edittext again.. but I dont know yet how to delete the item.. :( I've edited my question.. look the changes..

Comment: my answer is also correct... why did you unaccepted :( :( i try my best to help you and was very happy when you accept my ans ...

Comment: sorry man, because i tried your answer, but wasnt solve my problem..the 'view' was show error..with red underline.. and i dont knowed why. whence i need to find other way.. thanks! thank you very much!

Comment: did you create a method list ?? if yes then in which class ?

Comment: i tried again your solution. but this create a menu when i click on button settings (the tree dots on top left) and no menu item. how the menu will know what is to delete? only if selected? sorry if sounds like noob :S

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I win!.. now, I can edit and delete the item from listview...

```
private Button bt;
private ListView lv;
private EditText et;
private ArrayList<String> Arraylt = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_l);

bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
lv.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int posicao, long id) {
         Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
         et.setText(String.valueOf(o));
         bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addadicionar();

    }
});

}   


public void addadicionar() {
Arraylt.add(et.getText().toString());
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arraylt));
et.setText("");
}
```

sorry for the bad indent..